# VBA change excel code during runtime AND execute it

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, runtime

I want to change a VBA code module in Excel and execute the new code.
Before starting the program:

```
SUB1()
  msgbox "O L D"
ENDSUB
Main program:
  Delete_SUB1
  Create_NewSUB1
  CALL SUB1
Remark: Create_SUB1 creates the follow code:
SUB1()
  msgbox "N E W"
ENDSUB
```

**Issue:** The code is changed BUT Excel still executes the old version. I've tried:

- A) `.ActiveCodePane`
- B) Switching between two workbooks
- C) open/close solves the issue but takes too long. (I need it in a loop 1000 times for an AI-application).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why can't you use Sub1 and Sub2?

Comment: This is an AI(artificial intelligence) project. The code will be generated by a neuronal net. This is only a simple excample. The AI should generate functions to solve non linear equotations. But the problem is. Excel is not able to run code which is created in runtime. If the issue above is solved - we can go on with creation of the neuronal network (functions which creates functions).

Comment: We want : a) functions which manipulates each other [function A updates B, B updates C, C updates A]  b) we want to learn if an AI comes to the same solutions as the math c) we want to create a neuronal net were the results (final generated code) can be intepreted by humans (humans learn from machines).

Answer (score 3):

I was about to write that this is not possible, however after playing around, I was able to find a way to do what you want.

The basic idea is to put the dynamic part into a separate workbook and call it via `Application.Run`. Doing so, the compiler seems to do its job, but only on the workbook having the dynamic code.

If code would be in the same workbook and you would find a way to compile the code, it would reset global vars, loosing the information where to continue execution and sooner or later either silently stop executing or crash.

I am **not** saying that this is a good idea or that this will work when running for a long time (and I think neuronal net runs very often until they get to a result). Especially you need to ensure that the dynamic code will never have any syntax error, else the whole process will be interrupted with an "Syntax error" message, and this cannot be handled with any `On Error...`-handler as it is not an runtime error.

This is the code I used for testing:

```
Global GlobalCount As Long ' Using a global to prove that it is not reset by compiler

Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 100
        CreateAndRunProc
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateAndRunProc()
    GlobalCount = GlobalCount + 1
    
    Dim code(1 To 3) As String
    code(1) = "Sub testOnTheFly()"
    code(2) = "    Debug.print " & """Hello " & GlobalCount & " at " & Time & """"
    code(3) = "End Sub"
    
    ' Write the Sub "testOnTheFly" into module "modTest" of Workbook "OnTheFlyChild.xlsm"
    WriteSub Workbooks("OnTheFlyChild.xlsm"), "modTest", code
    ' Call the newly created Sub
    Application.Run "'OnTheFlyChild.xlsm'!testOnTheFly"
End Sub

' Replace the complete code of module with the provided code
Sub WriteSub(CodeWB As Workbook, moduleName As String, code As Variant)
    Dim project As VBProject, component As VBComponent
    Set project = CodeWB.VBProject
    Set component = project.VBComponents(moduleName)
    
    component.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, component.CodeModule.CountOfLines
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(code) To UBound(code)
        component.CodeModule.InsertLines i, code(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Have fun!

Comment: The idea sounds good. I will try and I am curious, if the second workbook code can update the code in the first workbook. Let me test.

Comment: Voted it up! I did that in my projects. You can also insert a module if `moduleName` is not found between existing components. But, in such a case, it is necessary to name the `testOnTheFly` procedure a little different. To make it contain part of the newly inserted module name. This would be necessary in order to avoid trying to run a procedure having the same name in another module...